# Get last modified information for Planner tasks

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

Is there any way to use Microsoft Graph to query for the last modified information for Planner tasks?

The [delta query](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview#supported-resources) doesn't seem to support task resources yet.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, there isn't a "modified date" property in [plannerTask](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannertask) object. The best you could do here would be sort by `createdDateTime` to see which tasks were added after a given date/time.